# vuetify treeview arrow mark is not showing correctly

Tags: vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify treeview, it's functioning correctly but I didn't get the collapse arrow. Here is the code and result

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-row>
            <b-col md="12" class="p-0">
                <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </div>
</template>
```

data

```
 data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'name': 'root',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            'name': 'child',
                            'children': []
                        }
                    ]
                ]
           }
    }
```

also I have attached these fonts in index.html

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

here is the result I got

[image]

when I inspect the code it's showing `$subgroup` variable inside the button like this

```
<button type="button" class="v-icon notranslate v-treeview-node__toggle v-icon--link material-icons theme--light">
  $subgroup
</button>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have missed the `vuetify: new Vuetify()` in the Vue constructor. Just add that and it will work.